# Understanding of the Word "Circulation" when Referring to Motion

Tags: meaning

I'd like to understand the meaning of the word 'circulation' when speaking about motion.

When thinking about directly sensually accessible processes (f.e. something that we can *see*), does the idea of circulation refer to a (f.e. spatially) *circular* process?
Or is it perhaps more about something like a closed system?

**EDIT:**
My question is about motion that is described as circulatory.

Comment: Please add a dictionary definition and link for the word in your question.

Comment: It would help immeasurably if you could be specific about what you want to know. Circulation of what? (And there's a similar ambiguity with *[circular](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circular)* which can mean returning to the start or prescribing a perfect circle or twisty and convoluted.)

Comment: Is **f.e.** an abbreviation of 'for example'?

Comment: Circular motion itself is usually refered to as *rotation*.

Comment: 'Arriving at the meeting early, he circulated, renewing many acquaintances' just means 'went round [the other guests]'; as Kate says, linear motion isn't intended, but a perfect circle would also be ludicrous. There _is_ an idea of fairly complete coverage though in both 'circulate' and 'go round [the room]'.

Comment: Unless you give us a specific example of a sentence with the usage you mention, nobody can know what you mean.

Comment: @WeatherVane It can also be *revolution*. Earth rotates around its axis every day, and revolves around the Sun every year.